# Pure Javascript menu diner prompt as output, input from choices

Tags: javascript

So I'm in a coding boot camp and am in my 4th week. I'm loving it but am feeling overwhelmed at times. That's part of the learning process though so I'm good with it. Anywho, I've been learning JavaScript the past 4 days and our homework is to build out a Diner Menu.

We learned how to nest objects today and forEach loops yesterday and arrow functions I think yesterday as well. I really like them and am wanting this project to be as dynamic as possible. I'm having trouble getting my main menu to post in the console however. I found a maybe solution on this site but I can't get it to work. Maybe I should just accomplish it all a simpler way but I really want to keep my menu items nested as they are. Here's what I have so far.

```js
        console.log ("Welcome to HotHamTawk!")
        console.log ("Where there are only three options and a few sides but that's it because it's dirt cheap and we don't care. And we don't make change!")
        console.log ( "Now pick your first item already, people are waiting!")
        
        const render = ({name, price}) => {
        return(`${name} => $${price}.00`)
        }
        
        
        function resetValuesToZero (obj) {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
                if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                    return resetValuesToZero(obj[key]);
                }
                obj[key] = 0;
            });
        }
        
        const main = {
          hotdog : {name : "Hotdog" , price : 1},
          hamburger : {name : "Hamburger" , price : 2},
          taco : {name : "Taco" , price : 1}
        }
          
        const side = {
          beans : {name : "Beans" , price : 1},
          chili : {name : "Chili" , price : 1},
          soda : {name : "Soda" , price : 1}
        }
        
        console.log(main.hamburger.taco.name); // 70
        resetValuesToZero(main);
        console.log(main.hamburger.taco.name); // 0
        
        
        // console.log(render(main.key))
```

So right now I'm trying to get a prompt to output that will say:

```
Hotdog => $1.00
Hamburger => $2.00
Taco => $1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code so I rewrote it.

```js
console.log ("Welcome to HotHamTawk!")
console.log ("Where there are only three options and a few sides but that's it because it's dirt cheap and we don't care. And we don't make change!")
console.log ( "Now pick your first item already, people are waiting!")

const render = type => {
  const output = [`${type} Menu:`];
  Object.values(menu[type]).forEach(({name, price}) => {
    output.push(`${name} => $${price.toFixed(2)}`);
  });
  return output.join('\n');
}

const main = {
  hotdog : {name : "Hotdog" , price : 1},
  hamburger : {name : "Hamburger" , price : 2},
  taco : {name : "Taco" , price : 1}
};

const side = {
  beans : {name : "Beans" , price : 1},
  chili : {name : "Chili" , price : 1},
  soda : {name : "Soda" , price : 1}
};

const menu = {
  'Main' : main,
  'Side' : side
};

console.log(render('Main'));
console.log(render('Side'));
```

---

Comment: Thanks! That's beautiful and exactly what I needed!